# Modify/Load content of CDN JS in PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a website where-in a plugin loads variable, which contains a CDN JS file. This CDN JS file writes some HTML onto my website using `$document.write();`

Now, I want to modify the content of this `$document.write();` How can I load the result of the CDN request to a variable?

For eg:
My PHP code is:

```
$var = '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://edeetion.com/ebayproxy/index.js.php?&requestType=EBaySeller&sellerID=holyheadmusic&maxEntries=2&openlink=_blank&categoryId=&sortOrder=EndTimeSoonest&item.filter(0).name=ListingType&item.filter(0).value(0)=All&sourceSite=3&floatorder=floating&displaydate=true&proxy_display_language=en"></script>';
echo $var;
```

Now what ever this script call I want to store it in a variable & later echo onto my website.
Instead it is just echos this script. This script is envokes & the `$document.write` does its stuff. I don't have any control over it.

I have tried one solution using `preg_replace()` but it will only work if the HTML content could be loaded into a PHP variable.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing as it might be useful for someone else.

Found the **solution**:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($resp);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$src = $xpath->evaluate("string(//script/@src)"); 

$Vdata = file_get_contents($src);
```

This way `$Vdata` contains the content of the CDN JS & I can modify its content further using `preg_replace();`

So the hero here is `file_get_contents();`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use that script on your server? because what you are doing now is trying to process script from your server only which is defeating purpose of having CDN. Instead use it on your server and then you will have complete control over it.

Comment: It's a script generated by a tool I'm using. It's dynamic & parameters keep changing hence I can't make it local.